# Which Magento 2 version is best to use

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I want to build an e-commerce site and I'm new to Magento.

Could you please suggest which **version of Magento** to use that is stable and has more extensions available in marketplace. Also, please suggest some of the security extensions that can be used to prevent the site from spammers and bots.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Magento Open Source** (Free)

> magento 2.4.2 is best for you but  you need elasticsearch service on server if you don't have elastic search then go with 2.3.7

Magento Open Source was previously known as Magento Community Edition. The first Magento Community Edition was released on June 24, 2008. Like its namesake, Magento Open Source is an open-source eCommerce platform that’s free to use.

This means that anyone can get the code of the software, edit it, and host it on their own server. With Magento Open Source you can extend its basic features by adding new plug-in modules and make configuration adjustments to meet the specific requirements of your business. However, to change the code you will need help from certified Magento developers.

Magento Open Source might be a good solution for small businesses or startups as this version has great features with minimum expenses. It can be downloaded and launched quickly by working on it immediately.

The latest actively supported versions of Magento Open Source are  **2.4.2. and 2.3.7.**

**Magento Commerce**

Magento Commerce was first released on April 15, 2009, as Magento Enterprise Edition. Over the years, the platform has evolved and changed its name along the way. The next step once you decide to move to Magento Commerce is to decide whether you want to go with Magento Commerce or Magento Commerce Cloud. Both editions are an exclusive paid version of Magento with premium and more extensive features.

**Magento Commerce (On-Premises)**

Magento Commerce (previously Magento Enterprise Edition) is an on-premises version which means that you have to take care of the hosting yourself. You can choose to host it on your business’ own server, in the cloud, with a hosting service, or through a software-as-a-service (SaaS) provider. Operating its own hosting requires a dedicated team to perform technical support, configuration, maintenance, and troubleshooting. Therefore, Magento Commerce is more suitable for large businesses that have a big team of in-house developers that has experience in running enterprise-level on-premise systems.

As mentioned previously, when compared to Magento Open Source, to operate on Magento Commerce, you must pay a yearly license fee. However, you get advanced platform features and functionalities such as B2B functionality, advanced marketing tools, customer segmentation, additional payment options, and Elastic Search (best in class search functionality).

**The latest actively supported version of Magento Commerce is 2.4.2.**

**Magento Commerce Cloud (Hosted)**

Magento Commerce Cloud (previously Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition) is the newest Magento product that was released with Magento 2. It’s a SaaS solution that’s hosted on Magento’s custom AWS-based cloud hosting infrastructure. With Magento Commerce Cloud, you get the benefits of Magento Commerce minus the work associated with self-hosting. You don’t need to worry about servers, networks, or even cybersecurity. This edition offers a scalable solution, built-in functionality, and performance improvements via Fastly’s image optimization and CDN. You also get to pass over the burden of security, PCI compliance, and maintenance to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of magento which is magento 2.4.2 is best possible solution for your e-commerce site.It consists of all e-commerce solutions.

Comment: Is it a stable version? Is it a beta release or a production ready release?